# django allauth isn't sending verification email after signup

Tags: python, django

I'm using django allauth for my user accounts. When I create an account, it successfully tells me it will send an email to the address for verification. However I don't receive this email.

This is my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SIGNUP = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: have you set AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS?

Comment: change your EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Comment: Yes I have set AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. still not working. @user6837382

Comment: I am running my website on local host and not on server yet, I'm using a Gmail account for now as testing. @Sachin

Comment: @Hi3e is your system connected to internet?? if yes please show me views.py from where you are sending mail.

Comment: @Sachin Singh.. my system is connected to the internet, i use django allauth i believe this is an in built without views.py.